# When using @ManyToOne on join field definition, I get an unresolved property exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, associations, many-to-one

I have the following @Entity's:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
public class Devices extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "asset_tag")
    private Integer asset_tag;

    @Column(name = "token")
    private String token;

    @Column(name = "last_seen")
    private String last_seen;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "device"
    )
    private Set<Tracking> trackings;


    public Devices() {
        super();
    }

    public Devices(Long id, String name, Integer asset_tag, String token, String last_seen) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.asset_tag = asset_tag;
        this.token = token;
        this.last_seen = last_seen;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Devices setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getAsset_tag() {
        return asset_tag;
    }

    public Devices setAsset_tag(Integer asset_tag) {
        this.asset_tag = asset_tag;
        return this;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public Devices setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
        return this;
    }

    public String getLast_seen() {
        return last_seen;
    }

    public Devices setLast_seen(String last_seen) {
        this.last_seen = last_seen;
        return this;
    }

    public Set<Tracking> getTrackings() {
        return trackings;
    }

    public Devices setTrackings(Set<Tracking> trackings) {
        this.trackings = trackings;
        return this;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tracking")
public class Tracking extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "reported_lat")
    private Float reported_lat;

    @Column(name = "reported_lng")
    private Float reported_lng;

    @Column(name = "normalized_lat")
    private Float normalized_lat;

    @Column(name = "normalized_lng")
    private Float normalized_lng;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_id")
    private Devices device;

    public Tracking() {
        super();
    }

    ...

}
```

My repository interface is defined as such:

```java
public interface TrackingRepository<A>  extends JpaRepository<Tracking, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tracking t WHERE t.device_id = :device_id ORDER BY t.created DESC")
    List<Tracking> getLastLocation(@Param("device_id") Long device_id, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tracking t WHERE t.device_id = :device_id AND t.created >= :time_limit ORDER BY t.created DESC")
    List<Tracking> getLastLocation(@Param("device_id") Long device_id, @Param("time_limit") Integer time_limit, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I build my project, when it is building the repository classes, I get the following exception:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: device_id of: com.vw.shuttle.model.Tracking [SELECT t FROM com.vw.shuttle.model.Tracking t WHERE t.device_id = :device_id ORDER BY t.created DESC]
at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)`
```

Why am I getting that exception? From the documentation I read, it seemed as though it should handle that mapping through the `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` annotations.

Comment: What is the definition of the Devices class?

Comment: Can't guess without seeing your Device entity. If it has an 'id' field the foreign key should be named 'device_id' so why the redundant `@JoinColumn` annotation?

Comment: Updated with Device entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries should be defined in terms of object properties and not columns i.e. `t.device.id` rather than `t.device_id`

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Tracking t WHERE t.device.id = :device_id AND t.created 
           >= :time_limit ORDER BY t.created DESC")
List<Tracking> getLastLocation(@Param("device_id") Long device_id, @Param("time_limit") Integer time_limit, 
                                 Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed all the issues and it compiled immediately. Thank you! I had -no- idea that the queries were written as object properties. That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: The queries are JPQL and not SQL. You can however, if it is ever required, use a native SQL query by using the `nativeQuery` = true flag on the @Query annotation.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!